# AFNetworking and Authorization Header

Tags: go, afnetworking-2

I'm new to AFNetworking, and I'm trying to use it to talk to an API that I've written in Go. I'm having difficulty getting the Authorization header to work. I've subclassed AFHTTPSessionManager and configured it as follows

```c
+ (HMAPIClient *)sharedHMAPIClient
{
    static HMAPIClient* _sharedHMAPIClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedHMAPIClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HMBaseURL]];
    });

    return _sharedHMAPIClient;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if (self) {
        self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:RegistrationAPIKey
                                                               password:@"Doesn't matter what goes here."];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)hitTestEndpoint
{
    [self GET:@"testEndpoint" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
```

When I call -(void)hitTestEndpoint, I see the following headers in my server logs (Authorization is missing):

```
Key: Accept-Encoding Value: [gzip, deflate]
Key: Connection Value: [keep-alive]
Key: Accept-Language Value: [en;q=1]
Key: User-Agent Value: [TestApp/2 (iPad Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/2.00)]
Key: Accept Value: [*/*]
```

For comparison, when I hit the same endpoint with the following curl command,

```
curl https://api.example.com/v1/testEndpoint/ -u test_xqzwjcasogptbnpa:
```

I see the following headers:

```
Key: Authorization Value: [Basic eHF6d2pjYXNvZ3B0Ym5wYTo=]
Key: User-Agent Value: [curl/7.30.0]
Key: Accept Value: [*/*]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? -Thanks

**Update:**
I have added AFNetworkActivityLogger so that I can see each request. The Authorization header is indeed included. Also, I tried hitting http://headers.jsontest.com, which returns the HTTP request headers received from the client. The Authorization header **is** present in that output.

So, the problem must be with my server. I'm already logging all headers for each request, and I'm not sure where else to look. Going to tag this question with Go to see if someone has an idea.

**Update 2**:
I added a call to httputil.DumpRequest at the top of my request handler, and it also shows that the Authorization header is missing. By the way, any custom headers that I set do appear as expected. It's just the Authorization header that's missing.

**Here's the Go Code**:

```
func testResponse(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    // check output from DumpRequest()
    dump,err := httputil.DumpRequest(request,true)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println("Output of DumpRequest():")
    fmt.Println(string(dump))
    fmt.Println("============")

    fmt.Println("request.Headers:")
    for key, value := range request.Header {
        fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
    }
    fmt.Println("===============")

    // return some dummy JSON
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    rw.Write(PersonToJson(getPerson("2f6251b8-d7c4-400f-a91f-51e09b8bfaf4")))
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server log you're showing looks like the headers after Go has already parsed them. It would be helpful to see the raw, plaintext HTTP headers that Go received. That would tell you if Go is ignoring the header or if something upstream is stripping it out.

**Edit**: Not sure why Go would strip out the `Authorization` header before giving you the supposedly raw request. But I think the `Authorization` header is normally sent by the client only after making a previous un-authorized request and getting a 401 response from the server with a `WWW-Authenticate` header. Since it sounds like your client is sending the `Authorization` header out of the blue, maybe the Go server API is ignoring & stripping the header because it never asked the client to send it.

If you just want to send a simple auth token on every request, what if you simply used a made up `X-` header instead, since you indicated that other headers you set arrive just fine?

Comment: Good idea. I used DumpRequest to look at the entirety of the http request, and it's not present there either. I updated the question above with this info.

Comment: Actually yeah that works for me. I'm new to web dev and I was trying to do things the "right" way, but if using a custom header is just as good, I'll take it.